# Explain Analyze output has much higher execution time than the actual time

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora

Execution time on Aurora postgres is much higher than the actual query execution time from the line 1 of the explain analyze output.

actual time = 0.408..0.415 
Planning time = 2.293 ms 
Execution time = 1,357.518 ms

My understanding is that execution time is close to the sum of actual time and the planning time. We are unable to account for extra 1,354 ms in this particular plan. We have ran vacuum full on each of the tables, ran analyze although that maybe irrelevant. The cluster was exclusively used to run this experiment and there was nothing else running. Is there anyway to figure out where this extra time is spent?

Here is the output of the explain analyze:

```
Limit  (cost=350.18..350.23 rows=20 width=4) (actual time=0.408..0.415 rows=14 loops=1)   
    CTE user2role_0
    ->  Seq Scan on t33_userdim t33_userdim_1  (cost=0.00..5.56 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
          Filter: ((NOT deleted) AND (end_stamp = '32503680000000'::bigint) AND (sid = 1))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 103   CTE roleownership_cte_1
    ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=0.07..9.41 rows=22 width=4) (actual time=0.033..0.118 rows=50 loops=1)
          Hash Cond: (t39_filtereduserrolehierarchy.c437_ancestor_role_id = cte0.c1)
          ->  Seq Scan on t39_filtereduserrolehierarchy  (cost=0.00..8.48 rows=236 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.063 rows=236 loops=1)
                Filter: ((level >= 1) AND (end_stamp = '32503680000000'::bigint))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 63
          ->  Hash  (cost=0.04..0.04 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                ->  CTE Scan on user2role_0 cte0  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)   
    CTE opportunityteammembercte_2
    ->  Unique  (cost=8.04..8.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
          ->  Sort  (cost=8.04..8.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
                Sort Key: t36_opportunityteammemberdim.c401_opportunityid
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.45..8.03 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: (cte0_1.c1 = t36_opportunityteammemberdim.c409_userid)
                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=6.42..6.66 rows=24 width=4) (never executed)
                            Group Key: cte0_1.c1
                            ->  Append  (cost=0.00..6.36 rows=24 width=4) (never executed)
                                  ->  CTE Scan on roleownership_cte_1 cte0_1  (cost=0.00..0.44 rows=22 width=4) (never executed)
                                  ->  Seq Scan on t33_userdim t33_userdim_2  (cost=0.00..5.56 rows=2 width=4) (never executed)
                                        Filter: ((NOT deleted) AND (end_stamp = '32503680000000'::bigint) AND (sid = 1))
                      ->  Hash  (cost=1.01..1.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                            ->  Seq Scan on t36_opportunityteammemberdim  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                                  Filter: ((NOT deleted) AND (sid <> '-2'::integer) AND (end_stamp = '32503680000000'::bigint))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 1   ->  Sort  (cost=327.17..327.35 rows=72 width=4) (actual time=0.407..0.410 rows=14 loops=1)
        Sort Key: t257_oppfact.sid DESC NULLS LAST
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=14.32..325.25 rows=72 width=4) (actual time=0.301..0.400 rows=14 loops=1)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=13.89..202.35 rows=27 width=4) (actual time=0.286..0.340 rows=14 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (t257_oppfact.c913_opp_ownerid = t33_userdim.sid)
                    ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_279_t257_oppfact_sid_end_stamp_start_stamp_null on t257_oppfact (cost=7.30..195.69 rows=27 width=8) (actual time=0.223..0.272 rows=14loops=1) 
                        Index Cond: ((sid = ANY ('{2432720,2432721,2432722,2432723,2432724,2432725,2432726,2432636,2432635,2432637,2432638,2432639,2432640,280866}'::integer[])) AND (end_stamp = '32503680000000'::bigint))"
                          Filter: ((NOT deleted) AND ((hashed SubPlan 4) OR (hashed SubPlan 5)))
                          SubPlan 4
                            ->  CTE Scan on opportunityteammembercte_2 cte0_2  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
                          SubPlan 5
                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=6.42..6.66 rows=24 width=4) (actual time=0.166..0.172 rows=37 loops=1)
                                  Group Key: cte0_3.c1
                                  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..6.36 rows=24 width=4) (actual time=0.034..0.147 rows=51 loops=1)
                                        ->  CTE Scan on roleownership_cte_1 cte0_3  (cost=0.00..0.44 rows=22 width=4) (actual time=0.034..0.129 rows=50 loops=1)
                                        ->  Seq Scan on t33_userdim t33_userdim_3  (cost=0.00..5.56 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
                                              Filter: ((NOT deleted) AND (end_stamp = '32503680000000'::bigint) AND (sid = 1))
                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 103
                    ->  Hash  (cost=5.30..5.30 rows=103 width=4) (actual time=0.057..0.058 rows=101 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on t33_userdim  (cost=0.00..5.30 rows=103 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.037 rows=101 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((NOT deleted) AND (end_stamp = '32503680000000'::bigint))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3
              ->  Index Scan using t184_oppdim_sid_ptimestamp on t184_oppdim  (cost=0.43..157.06 rows=38 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=14)
                    Index Cond: (sid = t257_oppfact.sid)
                    Filter: (NOT deleted) 
Planning Time: 2.293 ms 
Execution Time: 1357.518 ms
```

Comment: What version?  What machine type? Is this reliably reproducible?  How long does it take to just run the query with EXPLAIN?  With EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)?

Comment: 12.11 and used db.x2g.4xlarge and db.x2g.8xlarge. It's consistently reproducible. Plan looks similar for just EXPLAIN, EXPLAIN ANALYZE and EXPLAIN( ANALYZE, TIMING OFF).